# query for show latitude longitude polygon in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, gis, polygon

i have a polygon and point

i use query to detect latitude longitude location point with query mysql `SELECT X(coord), Y(coord) FROM geometry`

and it works

but how to show vertices(points) polygon in mysql? like

```
POLYGON((
107.623303663647 -6.94958690332541,
107.623303663647 -6.94969839983204,
107.623038859444 -6.94970835487728,
107.623028904398 -6.94956699323494,
107.623303663647 -6.94958690332541))
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. `SELECT AsText(your shape) FROM your table;`

Comment: i try, but the result is BLOB.

Comment: click option in your result and check Show BLOB Contents